# is there any module to merge os and tkinter ? by running the code it shows filename in pycharm but number in tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, python-os

#well i want automation progress to pick file name by os mobule and place it as an label in tkinter

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")
root.config(bg="black")

def Anime():#anime function              #this fuction works well
    name = os.listdir("D:/anime")
    few = name[0:10]
    for list in few:
        print(list)

def label(ly):#tkinter label function  #but this shows number in label of tkinter
    label = tk.Label(root,width=50,text=list,fg="pink",height=2,bg="green")
    label.place(relx=0.3,rely=ly)
ly = 0
count = 0
while (count < 0.78):
    count = count + 0.07
    print(label( ly + count))

Anime()
```

Comment: `label()` function does not return anything, so what do you want to see on the line `print(label(ly+count))`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no module to merge `tkinter` and `os`.

To achieve what **I think** you want:

```py
from tkinter import *
import os

window = Tk()
window.title("Window")
window.configure(bg = "black")
HEIGHT = window.winfo_screenheight()
WIDTH = window.winfo_screenwidth()
RESOL = str(WIDTH) + "x" + str(HEIGHT+7) + "+" + str(-7) + "+" + str(0)
window.geometry(RESOL)

l = os.listdir()
x = WIDTH/2
y = 0

for item in l:
    Label(window, text = item, bg = "green").place(x = x, y = y)
    y += 30
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @HarshMakwana Please accept and upvote it if it worked. Thanks!